# WinJS.UI.ListView items not displayd

Tags: javascript, windows, winjs

Trying to display a sorted list in a div. But I get only an empty div.

HTML

```
<div id="contentDmChat" data-win-control="WinJS.UI.ListView">
</div>
```

JS-Code:

```
contentDmChat.itemTemplate = myTemplate;
contentDmChat.layout = WinJS.UI.ListLayout;
contentDmChat.tapBehavior = 'directSelect';
contentDmChat.selectionMode = 'single';
contentDmChat.itemDataSource = userMs;
```

List for data source has elements. 
Any idea?

Comment: At first glance: what is the userMs variable? If it's a WinJS.Binding.List you need to set itemDataSource to userMs.dataSource specifically.

Comment: Yes it is a WinJS.Binding.List but still the same result, also with userMs.dataSource.

Comment: Solved:
var list = document.getElementById("contentDmChat").winControl;
list.itemTemplate = 'myTemplate';
list.layout = WinJS.UI.ListLayout;
list.tapBehavior = 'directSelect';
list.selectionMode = 'single';
list.itemDataSource = sortedDmList.dataSource;

Comment: To clarify, then, you needed to make the correct reference to the template and to .dataSource?

Comment: Yes it only work with the code above. Adding only .dataSource didn't work.